# Android WebView won't load remote url from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, android, mobile, webview

I am building my first android application and having a issue. Basically i am trying to port my Youtube 2 Mp3 page built in PHP to a mobile application. I have successfully done this but the problem i am having is after converting to mp3 i am unable to download the mp3 file from the link printed on the page from the android app. It works fine directly from the webpage and it works fine if i have the app load the link in androids default browser ( Chrome ) but it does not work when i have the app load the link within WebView.

FILE: MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web.loadUrl("http://www.bigjohn863.com/youtubetomp3/index.php");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;

    }
}
```

WEBPAGE: http://www.bigjohn863.com/youtubetomp3/index.php

The webpage works as expected when loaded in a regular browser and it works fine if i use it in android default browser ( Chrome ), but if i change the code to only load clicked links in webview then when i click the link it does nothing.

[image: APP VIEW FROM BLUESTACKS]

Comment: Have you given a relative path for links? If possible please post your code which you had used for hyperlink

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?mp3=' + encodeURI(songFile) + '">Download your MP3 file</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` after you validate the `url`. It will start a download similar to downloading from any webpage

```
 if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                // Make a new request pointing to the .mp3 url
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
                request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                request.setTitle("YourMp3.mp3");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "MyMp3.mp3");
                // get download service and enqueue file
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }
```

Comment: I already have that in the manifest. It loads the page correctly which requires internet just the hyperlink on the page doesn't work in the android app.

Comment: Tell me if you are looking for this kind of functionality

Comment: And add the permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: You Sir ... Are The Man! Works like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: Hey man, how do i get the file name of the file downloading so i can save it to the sd card as the filename rather than YourMP3.mp3

Comment: String[] parts = string.split("/"); String filename = parts[parts.length-1]

Comment: it meant to be `String[] parts = url.split("/");  request.setTitle(parts[parts.length-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?mp3=' + encodeURI(songFile) + '">Download your MP3 file</a>
```

This code will defiantly not work in android web view because it contains the PHP code and PHP code is server side code and android web view can run only client side code.

If you want to run it then get the data from the server as URL and put it into the anchor tag or you can try with by putting an complete hard code URL inside anchor tag.

Comment: Yes that code is from the server side ... I was just showing you how the webpage generated the hyperlink per your request.